# Tier 2 (General) Visa - Maintenance (and accommodation) requirement

Tags: uk-visa

I have recently applied for my tier 2 (General) visa as a main applicant along with dependent - spouse and dependent - child visas. My sponsor has not sponsored maintenance. I have more than sufficient funds in my account. Therefore, I submitted my bank statement to meet the maintenance requirement.

I just came to know that maintenance is based on two aspects: (i) sufficient funds and (ii) accommodation.

I have, however, not booked any accommodation in UK and provided my sponsor's address as initial accommodation address after their consent, though this consent is not documented in CoS. Note that it is not a residential/ living address. Its a University address. Now, I am worried that my visa could be refused due to non-residential UK address specified on the application form. I am more concerned due to the fact that our Kid will be accompanying us and UK authorities are more strict regarding suitable accommodation of kids.

How can I amend this situation?

Comment: Please do not post personal identifying information on this site. There are no guarantees that this site isn't crawled for such data. I would recommend you sort out the living arrangements immediately and then send proof of those arrangements, with all relevant references to original application, to the Home Office. Send a cover letter along explaining your ignorance. Try to be humble. Good luck.

Comment: @ouflak thanks! Well, I have consulted few other people also and they mentioned that accommodation is required for only those people who are themselve in UK and trying to apply for their dependents from outsie the UK. Official website also states only two conditions for maintenance: (1) certified on CoS from A* Sponsor or (2) have sufficient funds to support maintenance - I believe I would be OK. Also, sending documents at this stage will not be helpful, as UKVI website states only those documents will be considered for decision making that were submitted with the application.